# How to reduce WhatsApp Desktop App RAM Usage?

Tags: catalina, memory, whatsapp.app

My problem is with WhatsApp itself. I know that modern browsing is RAM intensive (specially webapps built with Electron), but we close and open tabs all the time, which compensates for the RAM usage. But, for instance, my WhatsApp Desktop App (a glorified browser tab) is open **ALL** the time since it is a major work and personal tool for my digital life, and sacrificing 1GB of RAM for a communication application seems like overkill to me.

It consumes around 600MB to 1GB depending on its usage.

WhatsApp Renderer GPU is the most RAM intensive task.

I created an Automator App that runs this terminal command (I saw it [here](https://gist.github.com/marpontes/23cec835ac161d8d66c4c65e0c283434)):

```
open /Applications/WhatsApp.app/ --args --disable-gpu
```

But it stills open WhatsApp with the GPU renderer.

I would like to ask what could I do to force WhatsApp to be less RAM intensive or how to I stop making it use my GPU (since the terminal command above did not work).

Comment: I have been struggling with the same issue.
My Mac only has 8GB of RAM so over 1GB on Whatsapp is a waste. I have tried the browser version of Whatsapp and it consumes much less incremental RAM. Not quite as friendly...

Comment: Indeed, I hope they fix it soon. I could not find an solution that solves this problem yet.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Hopefully someone that’s skilled at tuning applications that actually run their own system can weigh in. It’s so easy to make a bad node/electron/whatever app - but it’s possible to do them well. Code by Microsoft seems to be superbly tuned and fast/responsive despite being architected equivalently.

Comment: it is worse. i just saw it use 3.08GB on mine.

Comment: Mine is using 2gb and doing nothing. This would help me a lot.

Comment: any solution? I have a brand new macbook pro with 32 gb ram and m1 max, not even 3D graphics requires fans, but as soon as I open Whatsapp they start running... like wtf

Comment: Your best option is to complain to the developer, in the hope that they improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web version instead of desktop version.